# Why battery symbol appear on display of multimeter ?

Tags: battery-charging

In my meter on display show a battery symbol, what is mean?

due to that, it doesn't test continuity test and not measure resistance.

can anyone help to solve this problem?

see a img.

[image]

Comment: That symbol indicates that the battery in the multimeter is low. You need to replace it. They can give very inaccurate readings when the battery is low.

Comment: IMportant lesson here. When in doubt, read the fine manual and replace with a Lithium 9V for longer life.

Comment: When you select 200 \$\Omega\$ range and touch the probes together what does the display read?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: "_read the fine manual_"; ROFL; good one!

Answer (score 9):

Usually you can measure the battery voltage while it is still in the meter.

- Open the back of the meter to expose the battery.
- Plug the red test lead into the V socket and switch to 20 V DC range.
- Touch the probe to each of battery terminals in turn. Record the voltages. The battery + will give a positive reading and the - a negative reading.
- Add the two readings together ignoring the minus sign. The total is the battery voltage.

Secure the meter back correctly when finished to avoid shock on future measurements.

Comment: A neat trick!!!

Comment: Thanks. I realised this almost forty years ago when I got my first Intersil LCD module, if I remember correctly. The module '0 V' remains a fixed offset from the battery negative and the battery + voltage falls as the battery ages. It has worked on any other meters I've tested since.

Comment: +1 for the measurement trick, however knowing what the battery voltage *is* doesn't tell you what it *means*. In my stable of (mostly) cheap meters, some throw the 'lo-bat' before they misread, some after, some peg out at 7v and some go all the way down to 3v still reading OK, and it's not always the dirt cheap ones that are the worst! If you have one meter, you should get a second, and then use them to check what each other's lo-bat indication *really* means.

Comment: @Neil_UK: Agreed. The resistance measurement is probably using a constant-current generator to convert resistance to a 200.0 mV signal at full scale. This might fail to operate correctly before the battery-low warning turns on.

Comment: @Transistor good point. I've only checked my meters on the volts range. Doing it on the ohms range explores an extra degree of freedom (complication) that the current generator may have a different working threshold to the voltage reference. On reflection, your self-check of battery voltage would work OK with a correctly reading meter, but could fail, and fail high, with a meter failing under low battery. So it really needs a second, well powered, meter to do the battery check job properly.

Comment: **Do not short the common (black) test lead to the battery as this will cause irreparable damage to your meter.** The manual tells you to remove the leads for a reason.

Comment: How do you know? ;^)

Comment: @Jeroen3, yes but the *amount of damage* will be a good indicator of the battery's health, so it's still a valid method.   :p

Comment: @Transistor Common is often directly ground. Probing ground to any of the terminals will short the supply (+/-) rails.

Comment: I know. I was familiar with the chip internals. I was asking how you knew. It read as though you had learned the expensive way. Following my instructions will not cause any harm.